# getline is not waiting for the input

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the n-th line from the standard input in the following program. However, the console will print out "current line  is" before I input any number...not sure what's wrong. Thanks for help.

```
int main()
{
    string currentLine;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << n << endl;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        getline(cin, currentLine);
        cout << "current line  is" << currentLine << endl;
        n--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has been asked so many times before...

Comment: Did try search other answers before posting, however,still cannot figure out why. not very good at c++

Comment: Just googling the name of your question brings up at least four duplicate S.O questions on the first page...

Comment: Yes, now I found a link n the right side. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatted input using `operator>>()` stops as soon as its format can't be satisfied by the next character. For integers it stops when there is no further digit, e.g., when the next character is a whitespace like the newline from entering the line.

`std::getline()` reads until it finds the first newline. There was one left right before when reading the integer. You probably want to extract this newline and potentially other whitespace. You could, e.g., use

```
if (std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, currentLine)) {
    // do something with the current line
}
else {
    // deal with a failure to read another line
}
```

The manipulator `std::ws` skips leading whitespace. As indicated above, you should also  verify that the input was actually successful before processing input.

Comment: `std::cin >> n >> std::ws` would skip the newline after the integer; `std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, … )` furthermore ignores all empty lines. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get `n`, you have to input a number and press the **Enter** button. As @Kuhl said, `the operator>>` stops as soon as its format can't be satisfied by the next character.

This means the first time `getline(cin, currentline)` runs will get **'\n'** !
Then the program will output "current line is\n" while the '\n' will not be shown on the console.

If you want to get `n` and 'currentline', you may choose the @Kuhl's answer or write the program like this:

```
getline(cin, currentline);

while(n>0) {
    // anything you want
}
```

The `getline(cin, currentline)` will help you to skip the `'\n'` followed by the number 'n'.